# Перегрузка операторов python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу понять что такое перегрузка операторов,читал в гугле,но не разобрался.Не кидайте камнями что я не пошел дальше гуглить,а спрашиваю у вас.Просто от человека к человеку информацию быстрее понять можно,чем свайпить кучу стариц гугла.Если кто надумал пояснить,давайте с небольшими примерами которые пригодятся на практике,пожалуйста:)

Comment: Перегрузка операторов https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/peregruzka-operatorov.html

Comment: Попробуйте прочитать в учебнике.

Comment: Страницы гугла наполняются такими же людьми, как и мы. Страницы учебников тоже

Answer (score 1):

Перезагрузка операторов - это описание логики для случаев нестандартного использования операторов, например, для пользовательских объектов.

Скажем, есть объект площадь:

```
class Square ():
    def __init__(self, length, depth):
        self.length = length
        self.depth = depth
        self.square = self.length * self.depth
```

И есть объект высота:

```
class Height:
    def __init__(self, height):
        self.height = height
```

Для получения объема нужно перемножить площадь на высоту. Если "втупую" перемножать, то получим ошибку:

```
s = Square()
h = Height()
v = s * h
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Square' and 'Height'
```

Вот тут и поможет перезагрузка оператора умножения. 
Синтаксис перезагрузки ищите самостоятельно.

Comment: Слова правильные, к код не очень. Классы на Python так не пишут.

Answer (score 1):

Перегрузка операторов - это указание какие действия будут выполняться при применении, например, арифметических операторов к объектам ваших классов. К примеру, что будет происходить, если вы попробуете сложить два объекта. Это не всегда нужно, но часто бывает полезно.

Для примера, в Java нет перегрузки операторов, поэтому с по сути числовым типом `BigDecimal` приходится работать не с помощью арифметических операторов (`+`, `-`, `/`, `*`), а с помощью методов (`add`, `subtract`, `divide`, `multiply`):

```
...
BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for (Instrument instrument: cart.getInstruments()) {
    sum = sum.add(instrument.getPriceForDay());
}
sum = sum.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(cart.getDays()));
...
```

Аналогичный код на Python с типом `Decimal`:

```
summa = Decimal(0)
for instrument in cart.instruments:
    summa += instrument.price_for_day  # оператор += перегружен

summa *= cart.days  # оператор *= перегружен
```

В данном случае в примере на Python читаемость кода намного лучше. Но злоуптреблять перегрузкой также не стоит - не нужно делать перегрузку просто так, "чтобы было".

---

Синтетический пример с перегрузкой операторов: есть класс "веревка". У веревки есть только одно свойство - длина. Веревку мы можем удлинить (привязать другую веревку, длину входяющую в узел при удлинении для простоты не учитываем).

```
class Rope:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self._length = length

    def __len__(self):
        # Переопределяем оператор len
        return self._length

    def __add__(self, other):
        # Переопределяем оператор +
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            # Если второй объект (то с чем складываем) того же класса
            return Rope(self._length + other._length)  # возвращаем новый объект
        elif isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            # Если второй объект - число
            return Rope(self._length + other)  # возвращаем новый объект
        else:
            raise TypeError

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        # Переопределяем оператор +=
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            # Если второй объект того же класса
            self._length += other._length  # изменяем существующий объект
            return self
        elif isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            # Если второй объект - число
            self._length += other  # изменяем существующий объект
            return self
        else:
            raise TypeError


rope = Rope(10)  # новая веревка длиной 10

rope1 = rope + 10  # или rope1 = rope + Rope(10)
print(len(rope))  # Вывод: 10 (длина исходной веревки не изменилась)
print(len(rope1))  # Вывод: 20

rope += 12  # или rope1 += Rope(12)
print(len(rope))  # Вывод: 22

rope += 'rope'  # TypeError
```

Comment: Согласен, Ваш код выглядить более pythonic, чем мой - я специально не разжовывал, что бы пользователь самостоятельно поискал информацию.

Comment: @ViktorIlyenko, даже без учета разжевывания: свойства объектов не задаются прямо в теле класса. Если нужно свойства объекта задать (а не класса), то их нужно указывать в методе `__init__`. Ну и нет необходимости создавать отдельный класс для высоты, для этого достаточно существующих числовых типов.

Comment: И тут соглашусь, исправил свой ответ с Вашими рекомендациями